# Why i am getting this error while calling API

Tags: javascript, api

[image]

```
var path = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=";
var city = "London";
var apiKey= "&appid=eb5eacd85411228f461a151003d9bf07";
var url = path + city+ apiKey;



function getTemp(){
fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  var nameValue= data.name;
  var tempr = data.main.temp;
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML= nameValue;
  document.querySelector("h2").innerHTML= tempr;


})}
getTemp();
```

I am getting error while running this code. Please help me fix the issue here.

Comment: `data.main` does not exist.  Use the Network Inspector to see what JSON is actually returned.

Comment: Because `data.main` is undefined. The JSON has some properties called `main` but they aren't at the top level. You have to deal with the data structure you have. You can't just name something deep inside it and have it appear.

Comment: `data.main` is undefined. Add a `debugger;` and `console.log(data)` in the code  see what properties the `data` object has

Comment: `main` is a property on your objects inside `data.list`, not `data`

Answer (score -1):

the structure of the response on this API is not returning `data.main.temp` directly, the top level of this api returns

```
"message": message,
  "cod": cod,
  "count": count,
  "list": [{"main": {"temp"}}]
```

so to access temp you should navigate into list or access the record you want directly like `data.list[index].main.temp` index can be 0 or whatever depends on your list size that is determined on `data.count`

Answer (score -2):

I think this(data.main) might not be coming from response.
Try console logging the the whole response, and check if the response is coming or not.

fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))